# Open connection properties of selected table

Tags: excel, vba

I'm newbie to VBA so I will need your help.

**What I want?**
A VBA code that opens the Data > Properties > Connection Properties > Definition of the selected table.

Don't know if it's important but I'm trying with a table imported from SAS.

**What I tried?**
Record the macro to check the steps needed.

**The problem I found?**
The recorded macro shows the steps I need to the table I selected, but refers to specific name, not no "active table".

The code of the recorded macro:

```
Sub teste()
'
' teste Macro
'

'
    Range("D4").Select
    With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("(Default) MY_TABLE_NAME").OLEDBConnection
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .CommandText = Array("MY_TABLE_NAME")
        .CommandType = xlCmdTable
        .Connection = Array( _
        "OLEDB;Provider=MY_PROVIDER_LOCATION;Mode=Read|Sha" _
        , _
        "re Deny None;Use TK Manager Search Path=False;SAS Data Set Creation Code Page=0;SAS ValidMemName Read Update=False;SAS Adjust St" _
        , "arting Date 1900=False")
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .SavePassword = False
        .SourceConnectionFile = _
        "MY_ODC_LOCATION"
        .SourceDataFile = ""
        .ServerCredentialsMethod = xlCredentialsMethodIntegrated
        .AlwaysUseConnectionFile = False
    End With
    With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("(Default) MY_TABLE_NAME")
        .Name = "(Default) MY_TABLE_NAME"
        .Description = ""
    End With
    ExecuteExcel4Macro _
        "(""(Default) MY_TABLE_NAME"",TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,1,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,0,TRUE,""MY_ODC_LOCATION"")"
End Sub
```

Comment: What is your actual goal? To perform an action on the table with VBA or **just** to open the property dialog box (and perform no action on the table with VBA)? • If you just want to open the dialog box try `Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PowerQueryQueryProperties"` while a cell within the table is selected.

Comment: My goal is just to open. Will try that.

Comment: Gives the following error: Method 'ExecuteMso' of object '_CommandBars' failed

Comment: any help on this?